Batch: Renaming Files in Powershell or Linux
I need to rename a bunch of image files because of formatting issues.
The current image file names follows the format:
thermal_site_YYYY_MM_DD_HHMMSS.tiff

But the format it needs to be in is:
thermal_site_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.tiff

There are hundreds of these photos and I really do not want to rename every single filename format.
Help! I need to keep the date and timestamps reading as the date/time they are.
I use cygwin-64 but have little experience in Linux.
I've tried:
$ find . -depth -name "*2024_08_15*" -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; mv -- "${f%2024_08_15}20240815"' \;

In cygwin-64 I haven't had any success and I haven't even attempted Powershell yet.

If this is not a recurring task you may use a GUI tool like the one in the MS Powertoys - PowerRename.

Proper formatting has been applied to your post after the fact, but please format your posts properly yourself to begin with in the future.


A PowerShell solution, combining Get-ChildItem, Rename-Item, a delay-bind script block and the regex-based -replace operator:
Get-ChildItem . -File -Recurse -Filter thermal_site_*_*_*_*.tiff |
  Rename-Item -NewName { 
    $_.Name -replace '(?<=^thermal_site_)(.+?)_(.+?)_', '$1$2' 
  } -WhatIf

Note: The -WhatIf common parameter in the command above previews the operation. Remove -WhatIf and re-execute once you're sure the operation will do what you want.


I've tried:
$ find . -depth -name "2024_08_15" -exec sh -c 'f="{}"; mv -- "${f%2024_08_15}20240815"' ;

That's not quite it, rather:
find -name 'thermal_site_????_??_??_??????.tiff'|
sed "s/\(.*\)_\(..\)_\(.._.......tiff\)$/mv '&' '\1\2\3'/e"

